# Does garbage collector preserve order when compacting?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I know there is a lot of internal algorithms. But anyway - does garbage collector try to preserve order of referenced objects during compaction (Gen2, SOH)?
How do pinned objects affect the answer?

Why I'm asking - I have a memory dump and I'd like (with some high probability) guess objects creation time according to other objects around.

Comment: It doesn't go out of its way to intentionally reorder objects.  But sure, pinning messes this up.  Only obvious when it is still pinned when you made the dump, but you can't see that it once pinned but isn't pinned anymore.  Pretty common, there is a lot of pinvoke in the framework.

Comment: I was considering some business objects that are not probably pinned at al. I'm interested in their age compared to other objects (or among each other).